# Compare value in 2 excel sheet and sort by descending in VBA

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I'd like to use excel 2010 to realize a function to first compare values from 2 different Excel sheets and then sort them based on another column value.

## For example:

In sheet 1, I've got:

```
Name    Value
Test 1   100.5
Test 1   200.6
Test 1   300.3
Test 2   100.8
Test 2   200.6
Test 3   200.5
```

In sheet 2, I've got :

```
Name    
Test 1   
Test 1   
Test 1      
Test 3
```

what I want to achieve is if the name from sheet 1 is not in sheet 2, delete the whole line in sheet 1 and sort by descending the name based on the column value.

## **Desired:**

```
Name    Value
Test 1   300.3
Test 1   200.6
Test 1   100.5
Test 3   200.5
```

Here is what I get so far:

```
Sub test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer


On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")


lastRow1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastRow2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count


For i = 2 To lastRow1
    For j = 2 To lastRow2
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value, ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) < 1 Then 
                Rows(i).EntireRow.delete

              Exit For
           End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Please suggest and help. thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code so it is working:

```
Sub test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer


On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last used cell in column A
lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last used cell in column A

Dim same As Boolean
same = False

For i = lastRow1 To 2 Step -1 'bottom to top
    For j = 2 To lastRow2
    Debug.Print ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.

            If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                same = True 'set True if match

           End If
        End If
    Next j

                If same = False Then 'if no match
                    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                same = False
Next i

'sort
lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:B" & lastRow1).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("B2:B" & lastRow1), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Still thinking about the rest of the answer, but in advance I would advise you to start at the bottom of the list (so from lastrow to the second row) The reason for this is that you are removing rows which your counter does not take into account. You may also want to look into the MATCH function in Excel to see if a certain value is used in a list instead of going through the whole list.

Comment: can you be more specific for the delete function from last row to the second row? I've used the function Instr() to compare the cell value from different sheets, if cant find the name of sheet 1 in sheet 2, so the position returns 0, but it's not working well, please advice, thank you very much.

Comment: If you start at the top of the list and find at the 5th row a value that has to be deleted, and you delete that row, the for next loop will goto 6 but this is one row below the row you now want, namely the 5th which was the 6th row before the deletion of the 5th row. I hope this is clear, otherwise I will just have to try to explain it better

Comment: For the second part: if you still want to loop through the values in to compare the values use the StrComp function instead of InStr. This does not take into account any additional spaces though, so you should likely also want to use the Trim function to remove those.

Comment: This is really a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I want!